# How to sum value of diffrent arrays in Arrays Of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to sum the values of arrays inside an array.

```
const arr = [
{ key: 0, x: [4,5,6], y: [1,2,3,4]},
{ key: 0, x: [1], y: [] }

]

The expected output would be 26 ( 4 + 5 + 6 + 1 + 2 ...)
```

No idea how to do this, tried with `reduce` but I don't know how to access the other array.
Any help would be great.

Comment: Will all items have `x` and `y`? Will `x` and `y` always be the only attributes of type array? Will the arrays in `x` and `y` always contain only numbers? And, more importantly, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can try getting the sum of nested object's array first, then sum them up and return like the following way:

```js
const arr = [
  { key: 0, x: [4,5,6], y: [1,2,3,4]},
  { key: 0, x: [1], y: [] }
]

const sum = arr.reduce((a, c) => {
  const cTemp = Object.values(c).flat().reduce((aa,cc) => aa+cc, 0);;
  return a + cTemp;
}, 0);
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const total = [
  {key: 0, x: [4, 5, 6], y: [1, 2, 3, 4]},
  {key: 0, x: [1], y: []},
]
  .map(({x, y}) => [...x, ...y])
  .reduce((total, curr) => total + curr.reduce((a, b) => a + b), 0);
```

```js
const total = [
  {key: 0, x: [4, 5, 6], y: [1, 2, 3, 4]},
  {key: 0, x: [1], y: []},
]
  .map(({x, y}) => [...x, ...y])
  .reduce((total, curr) => total + curr.reduce((a, b) => a + b), 0);
  
  
  console.log(total);
```

Comment: Instead of using nested `reduce` (2 times), you can use `Array#flatMap` like [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67088757/9071943) to get all values into one array :)

Comment: @NguyễnVănPhong or move it to the mapping step: `.map(({x, y}) => [...x, ...y].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)).reduce((total, curr) => total + curr, 0);` Although, since it's the same thing, it can be extracted out `.map(({x, y}) => [...x, ...y].reduce(sum, 0)).reduce(sum, 0);`

Comment: Yes, it's the same in terms of time complexity (I guess). But to me, I prefer `flatMap` over one ^^! @VLAZ

Answer (score 1):

> No idea how to do this, tried with **`reduce` *but I don't know how to
> access the other array.***

You can create another function named `sum` to sum all values in an array. After that, at each object, you can use `Spread ...` to merge 2 arrays into one like this.

```js
const arr = [ { key: 0, x: [4,5,6], y: [1,2,3,4]},
              { key: 0, x: [1], y: [] }];

const sum = (arr) => arr.reduce((acc, curr) => acc+= curr, 0); 
const result = arr.reduce((acc, {x, y}) => acc += sum([...x, ...y]), 0);

console.log(result);
```

Another way is to use [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to get all values, then use `Array#reduce` to sum them.

```
const allValues = arr.flatMap(({x, y}) => [...x, ...y]);
const result = allValues.reduce((acc, curr) => acc+= curr, 0);
```

```js
const arr = [ { key: 0, x: [4,5,6], y: [1,2,3,4]},
              { key: 0, x: [1], y: [] }];

const allValues = arr.flatMap(({x, y}) => [...x, ...y]);
const result = allValues.reduce((acc, curr) => acc+= curr, 0); 
console.log(result);
```

> The `flatMap()` method *returns a new array* formed by applying a given
> callback function to *each element of the array*, and then flattening
> the result by one level

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```js
const arr = [{
    key: 0,
    x: [4, 5, 6],
    y: [1, 2, 3, 4]
  },
  {
    key: 0,
    x: [1],
    y: []
  }
]

var total = 0;
arr.forEach(function(value) {
  value.x.forEach(function(x) {
    total += x;
  });
  value.y.forEach(function(y) {
    total += y;
  });

});
console.log(total);
```